# How can I generate a scatter plot from lmm in R?

Tags: r, scatter-plot, lme4

The models are:

```
Model1 = lmer(V1 ~ V2 * V3 + V4 + (1|V5), data=data)

Model2 = lmer(V1 ~ V2 + V3 + V4 + (1|V5), data=data)
```

V1: numerical
V2: numerical
V3: factor with two levels
V4: factor with two levels
V5: Random variable

I want to generate a dispersion graph with V1 on the Y ax and V3 on the X ax, with two curves for the two levels of V4. I tried the function coef(), but I don't know the values I should use:

Model1
(Intercept)       V2  V3 V4  V2:V3

Model2
(Intercept)         V2   V3 V4

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to do with V2 which can vary. Do you want to fix is at some value? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. What exactly determines what you "should" use?

Comment: Perhaps sjPlot would be useful, in particular [plot_model()](https://strengejacke.github.io/sjPlot/reference/plot_model.html)